# What is the difference between Discrete and Continuous Random Variables?

Tags: random

What is the difference between Discrete and Continuous Random Variables?

Discrete Random Variable = takes countable or discretely determinable values. So, it is always listable. For example, digital signals.

Continuous Random Variable = takes continuous values. So, it always has a range. For example, analog signals.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

It merely depends on how the values are measured.  Think of a water faucet that is filling a mug drop by drop, that is a discrete filling.  If the water facet fills it with a water jet, it is filled continuously.